# SIM7000E 0 voltage at SIM_VDD

Tags: hardware

I have problem with my SIM7000E. My PCB scheme and design is aveliable here https://easyeda.com/jaka87/new-vetercek While sending AT commands I get error as if sim card is not connected.

I also put oscilloscope on SIM_VDD and did some measurement. To my surprise i always measure 0V even or reset and when changing from `AT+CFUN=0 to AT+CFUN=1`.
It should at least send some bursts right ?
Any idea why this is happening?

Scheme:
[image: Scheme]

Comment: Please edit your question and include your schematic as an image and your code formatted at "code" in this question.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks i finally found the source of the issue. It turns out i mixed two labels on the PCB and therefore had wrong capacitors on VCC and data...